# How to prevent socket io client (browser) from being overflowed with huge payload coming from server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, socket.io

I have a React.js client app and a Node.js server app and the Node.js app receives json data in real time via `socket.io` from another microservice. The JSON data is sent very often and this breaks the client app. For example:

- I stop the server but the client still receives data
- If I try refreshing the browser, it takes a lot of time to refresh
- It also used to disconnect and reconnect the sockets (I fixed this by increasing the `pingTimeout` but that did not solve the other problems)

I also used `maxHttpBufferSize` and `updateTimeout` by increasing them but that does not really help. Decreasing the `maxHttpBufferSize` stops the messages from being received but I want them to be received just in a manner which does not break my client application.

Any advices on what I can do to improve my situation?

EDIT:
It could also work if I do not send all messages but skip every second or so but I am not sure how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Backpressure can be implemented with acknowledgements:

- the client notifies the server when it has successfully handled the packet

```js
socket.on("my-event", (data, cb) => {
  // do something with the data
  // then call the callback
  cb();
});
```

- the server must wait for the acknowledgement before sending more packets

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.emit("my-event", data, () => {
    // the client has acknowledged the packet, we can continue
  });
})
```

Reference: https://socket.io/docs/v4/emitting-events/#acknowledgements

Note: using volatile packets won't work here, because the amount of data buffered on the server is not taken in account

Reference: https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#websocketbufferedamount

Comment: Hey,  I tried your sollution but then I get a timed out exception printing the response.